# Getting all attribute values from node by specifying the ancestor node using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Let's assume I have the following xml file:

```xml
<ModuleSets>
    <ServiceModuleSet Name="serverModules">
        <Modules>
            <ServiceModule Name="ServerModule1"/>
            <ServiceModule Name="ServerModule2"/>
        </Modules>
    </ServiceModuleSet>
    <ServiceModuleSet Name="testBenchModules">
        <Modules>
            <ServiceModule Name="testBenchModule1"/>
            <ServiceModule Name="testBenchModule2"/>
        </Modules>
    </ServiceModuleSet>
    <ServiceModuleSet Name="hostComputerModules">
        <Modules>
        </Modules>
    </ServiceModuleSet>
</ModuleSets>
```

I want to get all Attributes from `ServiceModule` node, by searching in the `ServiceModuleSet` node, where the Attribute Name equals `"serverModules"`.

I'm new to LINQ and tried the following code:

```cs
IEnumerable<string> allServerModules = from item in xmlDocument.Descendants("ServiceModuleSet")
    where item.Descendants("ServiceModuleSet").Any(attribute => attribute.Value == "serverModules")
    select (string)item.Attribute("Name");
    
foreach (var serverModule in allServerModules)
{
    Console.WriteLine(serverModule);
}
```

Unfortunately I don't get any results printed to the console. What is the right way to solve it using LINQ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xattribute.value?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_Linq_XAttribute_Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution proposal:

```cs
var parsedXml = XDocument.Load("sample.xml");

var serverModules = parsedXml.Descendants("ServiceModuleSet")
    .FirstOrDefault(set => set.Attribute("Name")?.Value == "serverModules");

var moduleNames = serverModules?.Descendants("ServiceModule")
    .Select(module => module.Attribute("Name")?.Value)
    .Where(value => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value));

if (moduleNames == null) return;

foreach (var moduleName in moduleNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(moduleName);
}
```

1. First I try to retrieve that `ServiceModuleSet`, which has a `Name` attribute equals to `"serverModules"`
   1.1 If there aren't any descendants (where the filter criteria is met) then we don't want to fail with an exception that's why I used `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`
   1.2 The same fault tolerance logic was applied for the `Name` attribute as well that's why I used null conditional operator (`Attribute("Name")?.`)
2. If I have found the desired node then I can look for its child nodes to ask for their `Name` attributes
   2.1 Yet again the null conditional operator is being used (`serverModules?.Descendants`) to make our code more robust
   2.2 The `ServiceModule` nodes may or may not have `Name` attribute that's why I used a combination of null conditional operator (`.Attribute("Name")?.`) and empty string filtering (`!string.IsNullOrEmpty`).
3. If I had succeeded and retrieved some data then I print them otherwise I early exit

Comment: Thanks for the solution and detailed explanation! Like I said I'm new to this topic and spend yesterday hours of trying and frustrating, but that was exactly what I was searching for. I guess my mistake was trying to do it, all in one LINQ statement, instead of splitting it up, in two queries.

Answer (score 0):

I like using a dictionary :

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = doc.Descendants("ServiceModuleSet")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Descendants("ServiceModule").Select(z => (string)z.Attribute("Name")).ToList());
```